# Comparing a particular column value for two rows in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows:

```
ID  Version Type  Value
121    1     A     100
121    1     B     200
122    2     A     300
122    2     B     300
123    3     A     300
123    3     B     300
124    4     A     420
124    4     B     420
121    3     A     410
121    3     B     410
```

I am trying to build a query which gives returns the rows where "Value" is different between Type A and Type B for same ID and Version.
For example, in the above scenario, ID and Version is Unique 5 times (121-1,122-2,123-3,124-4,121-3). I would look at "Type" for each unique group and compare "Value" for Type A and Type B. 
The above scenario should return:

```
ID  Version Type  Value
121    1     A     100
121    1     B     200
```

The above two rows are the only ones with different "Value" for unique ID and Version and among Type A and Type B.
Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What database engine are you using? MySql is one type, and while SSMS can connect to MySql, it's normally strongly associated with Sql Server, which is completely different than MySql.

Comment: Please tag the only DBMS that you are actually using.

Comment: Do you have only two types?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `exixts` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 
              from table t1 
              where t1.id = t.id and 
                    t1.Version = t.Version and 
                    t1.type <> t.type and 
                    t1.Value <> t.Value
             );
```

Comment: What are t and t1 in this case? I only have one table!

Comment: @SiddhantAggarwal. . . `t` & `t1` are table alias & they are belongs to same same table.

Answer (score 1):

You can join a table to itself:

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable] t0
INNER JOIN [MyTable] t1 ON t1.ID = t0.ID AND t0.Type <> t1.Type AND t0.Value <> t1.Value
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable] t0
INNER JOIN [MyTable] t1 ON t1.ID = t0.ID AND t1.Type = 'B' AND t0.Value <> t1.Value
WHERE t0.Type = 'A'
```

Comment: Aah I see! But Is it possible to suggest that t0.Type = A and t1.Type =B instead of t0.Type<> t1.Type?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two types, I am going to recommend a different result set format:

```
select id, version,
       max(case when type = 'A' then value end) as value_a,
       max(case when type = 'B' then value end) as value_b
from t
where type in ('A', 'B')
group by id, version,
having max(case when type = 'A' then value end) <> max(case when type = 'B' then value end);
```

I recommend this because a typical follow-on question might be "how big is the difference".

Comment: Is "group by t" a typo?

Comment: That works. But the grouping should be based off of id and version right? Not just id!

Comment: Only if the versions really will match.

Comment: @SiddhantAggarwal . . . Yes, it should be by both.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to approach this problem:

```
select * 
from t1 
where (id, value, version) in (select id, value, version
                      from t1 
                      group by id, value, version
                      having count(id) = 1);
```

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43f80b5e5067a85ef5db7fae727e7a9a)

Answer (score -1):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
SELECT MAX(Value), MIN(Value)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY ID, Version
HAVING MAX(Value)<>MIN(Value);
```

Comment: And when you execute this query what information do you have ? 1. You do not know from which combination of ID and version this values are from. 2. The results are not even close to the ones from the question. 3. What when you will have more than one combination of values into results, you will have a just some values in two columns...

Comment: The values will only be there if they are different for same ID and Version. I lived with that :D